# Java server-client interactions

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server that can host multiple clients, along with a client that can connect. I am trying to be able to choose one of the clients and say, send them a message via PrintWriter. I The code below is for reference, and may not even need to be used. i was just wondering if there was a way to send a message to a specific client instead of all of the clients. I don't have any idea where to start on this.. I can do server to client and client to server but I'd like server to client communication to be sent to a specific client

Client:

```
    import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main{
    private static Socket socket;
    private static PrintWriter printWriter;
    private static String inputLine;
    private static Thread thread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("What is the computer's IP address?");
        String Ip_addr = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter the IP number of the server to connect: ");
        String IP = Ip_addr;
        while (true) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Client running...");
                socket = new Socket(IP, 8080);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Main
{
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static BufferedReader threadReader;
    private static String inputLine;
    private static Thread thread;
    private static PrintWriter printWriter;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Thread cmd = new Thread(new Commands());
        cmd.start();
        while(ClientThread.Clients < 100) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ClientThread.Clients += 1;

                //Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Test.txt")); // Opens notepad on Windows.
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                printWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try{
                thread = new Thread(new ClientThread(clientSocket));
                thread.start();
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error 103 = failed to create thread."); break;}
            try{
                serverSocket.close();
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error 105 = failed to close socket.");}

        }


    }
}
```

thread for multiple clients:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ClientThread extends Thread{
    static Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String username;
    public static int Clients = 0;
    static String[] Names = new String[100];
    char EOF = (char)0x00;
    public ClientThread(Socket s){
        socket = s;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            in = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Client Connected from " + socket.getInetAddress() + ", " + Clients + " connected.");
            Names[Clients-1] = "Client" + (Clients) + " " + socket.getInetAddress();
            in.readLine();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(("Client Disconected from " + socket.getInetAddress()));
            removeClient((socket.getInetAddress()).toString());

        }


    }
    private void removeClient(String Inet) {
        int Location;
        String[] Storage = new String[Clients];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Clients; i++) {
            String line = Names[i];
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            String Name = st.nextToken();
            String IP = st.nextToken();
            if(IP.equalsIgnoreCase(Inet)) {
                //System.out.println("Client removed..");
            }else {
                Storage[j] = Names[i];
                j++;
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < Clients; i++) {
            Storage[i] = Names[i];
        }

        Clients--;

    }
}
```

any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on asking appropriate questions.  Hint: Just dumping out all your code and asking for someone else to modify it is not appropriate.  Try to solve the problem yourself, then when you hit something you don't understand, post a minimal set of code that demonstrates the problem and ask a ***specific*** question.

Comment: BTW, your code has a lot of problems.  Just for starters, if the first `try` block throws an exception you print the exception but then continue on with the `accept()` call.

Comment: I added a little more to the question, and thanks, I'll fix that

Comment: Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116162/1751640) how to make good, client - server, interaction.

Comment: @MouseEvent thanks, so should I be using an arraylist for my clients?

Comment: Could I create an array of sockets?

Comment: No, create an arraylist of `ConnectionToClient`, as told in that post. BTW upvote that post, if you find it helpful.

Comment: @MouseEvent, I wish I could but i cant bc of my rep, sorry.